# Alternative ways to output messages

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a service using Microsoft.NET framework 3.5 and I would like to send some status 
messages/notify on error without using the event log, a log file or by email.

Any tips on how I can achieve this/possible/wise?

Comment: Where do you want the status messages to go to? Your question is too open-ended to get a single right answer.

Comment: You've said how you don't want to do it but not how you do. Is your question actually, `How do you send messages other than using the above?`

Comment: Why do you not want to use the methods you described?

Comment: @Paperjam because no one checks the event log, or wants to be trained to read a log file, any emails explaining an error will likely be ignored.

Comment: @Oded yes the question is open-ended, I'm looking for options

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought about [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) ?

It can send email, or store entries on the database, or send messages remotely.

Have a look at the options it provides.

Comment: I have used Log4Net before but haven't checked out sending messages remotely, I'll do that now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You could log the errors into a database or event log, throw together a UI to read the DB/log, then fire off a text message whenever an error occurs.

If your text recipients' cell providers offer the feature, sending a text is as simple as sending an e-mail.

For example, to send a text to a Verizon phone, just e-mail `{number}@vtext.com`, where `{number}` is a 9-digit telephone number.

Here's a list of [SMS Gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways).